# Mutex, синхронизация не объекта между потоками на Objective-C

Tags: c, objective-c, многопоточность

Делаю приложение, в котором постоянно проходит обработка некоторой модели и чуть реже её отрисовка. Сначала делал вычисления в *NSTimer*, всё работало как надо, но таймер потребляет слишком много энергии и вообще не для такой задачи создан. Поэтому решил переделать в отдельный поток.

Из потока обработки информация поступает на вывод только через переменную класса по имени *roof* типа *CGContextRef* - в основном потоке эта штука регулярно отрисовывается. Очевидно, что без дополнительных манипуляций раньше или позже два потока попробуют обратиться к этой переменной одновременно, надо синхронизировать.

Для этого я пробовал использовать и *NSLock*, и mutex классического *pthread* (он ведь совместим с *NSThread*?), но бестолку, со временем сей равно вылетает та же ошибка. *@synchronized* не подходит, так как принимает только объекты какого-нибудь класса.

Сам поток создаю стандартным способом:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(thread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

NSLock использовал так:

```
// Interface:
NSLock *locker;

// In awakeFromNib:
locker = [NSLock new];

// Everywhere I use roof:
if ([locker tryLock]) {
    // ...using of the roof...
    [locker unlock];
}
```

А pthread так:

```
// Interface:
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

// In awakeFromNib:
pthread_mutexattr_t attributes;
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attributes);
pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attributes, PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL);
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &attributes);

// Everywhere I use roof:
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
// ...using of the roof...
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Что я закодил неверно?

Comment: Отбой тревоги; я ошибся в том, что не во всех местах синхронизацию поставил. Исправил, проверил: оба способа работают как надо. В общем, всегда проверяйте окольные пути использования общих переменных. Вопрос оставлю, может кому-то пригодятся эти две заготовки мутексов.

Comment: ну удаляйте тогда

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko [справка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) говорит о том, что надо делиться знаниями. На ruSO я не нашёл записей про mutex на ObjC, так что пусть лучше останется. Думаю, модераторы со мной согласятся.

Comment: тогда публикуйте свой ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отбой тревоги; я ошибся в том, что не во всех местах синхронизацию поставил. Исправил, проверил: мутекс от *pthread* работает так же корректно, как и *NSLock*.
В общем, всегда проверяйте окольные пути использования общих переменных. Вопрос оставлю, возможно кому-то пригодятся эти две заготовки мутексов.

И если что, полезные ссылки по теме:
[Про варианты синхронизации и NSLock](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) на Apple Developer,
[Про pthreads](https://habrahabr.ru/post/248651/) на Хабрахабре.